# Como fazer esse efeito em css?

Tags: html, css

Olá, gostaria de saber como aplicar esse efeito em CSS.

Não sei descrever como se chama essas listras na vertical.

Também gostaria de saber como faz esse traço dentro de uma div.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já grato.

Comment: você utiliza bootstrap?

Comment: Eu sei usar, mas não preferia, porque é um exercicio e não sei se pode utilizar frameworks

Comment: Pro segundo caso não é só usar um `<hr>` estilizado?

Comment: as listras eu descobri... http://tableless.com.br/criando-listras-com-css3/
agora pra linha branca você pode usar um <hr/>

Comment: Raphão, é exatamente isso que eu precisava, irmão.

Comment: Você pode usar a ferramenta http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ para criar as listras e gradientes, e o código em CSS é gerado automaticamente, só copiar e colar.